# Chrome extension - Authenticate using web site and return API key to extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension which will make API calls to a web app i built. I want to implement authentication into the extension in order to make the API call and perform other tasks in the extension.

I want to use OpenID for the authentication (Using Azure) so my thinking was:

1. Chrome extension launches and background script opens popup to the login page of my web app
2. User is redirected to Azure login and enters credentials
3. Webapp receives openid token with user details
4. Webapp generates api key and stores this along with user id in back-end

The next part i'm not sure on is how i return the api key and userid back to the extension.

My thinking was to generate a 'login successful' page which has this data stored in a hidden field that the browser extension can then grab via a content script and store it in local storage.

Looking for advice on whether this is a suitable method or if there is a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you had a look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow ? You could store the token with the extension store (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/)

Comment: Yes i've seen that but that method wouldn't pass through my web app, it would just go to the OAUTH provider directly.